# Record audio 96kHz/24bit in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, recording

I am trying to write an audio-recording App for a comparison of the internal iPhone mic and an external lightning mic. The external mic is using **96kHz/24bit** which I do not want to change. So in order to compare on equal grounds I need to get a recording with the same parameters done in iOS.

I did some research and found out that playing **96kHz/24bit** audio is not possible on iPhones. Yet I found an inkling that the audio chips in an iPhone6 should be capable of working with Hi-Res audio. I tried to record using the `AVAudioRecorder`, but setting it up to **96kHz/24bit** gave me errors.

Do I need to take another Framework? On a lower level?

Comment: Have you found a solution to record at 96kHz?

Comment: @PavelAlexeev No sorry, I have not. This was part of my bachelor thesis and I did not have the time to try out much. I still think that openAl or AudioUnit could work but I do not have tried that.

Comment: I've asked a similar question here, but without much luck :(  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376673/ios-record-at-96khz-with-usb-microphone/34402922